# RegEx find all matches not present in the following set

Tags: regex, regex-group, regexp-replace

How to perform a regex replace on the dot symbol that is not present within a specific match (for example in an image HTML tag)

```
str = "Hi. the symbol before me is my match target <img src='http://skip.these.dots/and.this.as.well' alt='me.three' /> but still match this."
```

To be replaced with (for example) * symbol

```
res = "Hi* the symbol before me is my match target <img src='http://skip.these.dots/and.this.as.well' alt='me.three' /> but still match this*"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\.(?![^<]*\/>)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QmjAEN/2/)

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
\.      # match period
(?!     # begin negative lookahead
  [^<]* # match 0+ chars other than '<'
  \/>   # match '/>'
)
```

The negative lookahead fails if it encounters `/>` after the period without any intervening `<`, meaning the period must be between a `<` and an `/>`.

You wish to replace each match of a period with `*`. How you do that depends on the language you are using, but it is undoubtedly straightforward.